# How to avoid static website blinking when loading a page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, internet-explorer-9

I have a fully static website with couple of pages. Most of them contain just images, but two of them are also displaying list of news, which I decided to paginate with the use of [jQuery plugin pajinate](https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate).

The problem is, that when I click between the static pages, it looks like they just *swap* the content. But once I click a page with the pagination on it, the whole page *blinks*, as in the browser display a blank page and then renders the content and displays it.

I've tried to put all the JavaScript to the bottom right before `</body>`, but that doesn't seem to help at all.

[Here's a link](http://shalamarrestaurant.cz/specialities.html), when you click on any menu item other than *New Specialites* or *New Offers* it loads instantly, but those two make the page blink due to loading JavaScript.

**Is there any way to avoid this?** I'm testing this in Google Chrome, and it seems to do the same thing on Windows and on Mac OS X.

Comment: Looks ok here - didn't see any blinking in Firefox

Comment: @psynnott yes it's Google Chrome specific issue

Comment: @Darth It also occurs in IE9...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blinking does not happen if you remove the reference to the script:

```
https://raw.github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate/master/jquery.pajinate.min.js
```

Have you tried asking at https://github.com/wesnolte/Pajinate/issues about this?

**Edit**: Also, saving jquery.pajinate.min.js locally and using it seems to mitigate the blinking issue.